# Strange difference in ng-src expression evaluation when migrated Angular 1.2 to 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry about the unspecific title, not sure how to phrase. Experiencing some strange behaviour upon upgrading 1.2 to 1.3. /image is a route that will return a default image when the request is undefined. Previously if a and b were undefined this would be correct

```
<img ng-src="http://url.com/image/{{ a || b }}"/>
```

However upon upgrading Angular this expression, in the rendered HTML, returns:

```
<img
```

And there is no image. Have looked at the upgrade notes but couldn't see anything that would alter the behaviour?

Comment: provide  demo that replicates this

Comment: I know that I'm not answering the question, but if it's a one place problem you could just use `<img ng-src="http://url.com/image/{{ a || b || ''}}"/>`

Comment: @potato thanks, already did something similar to fix the problem, was wondering more conceptually if i was doing something incorrect :)